# Compare database time with server time

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i compare the created at time in database when the records is inserted and the server time when the record is selected for comparision times:
For now i have this:
In postgreSQL database field my records have: 2019-12-16 02:22:02 the field type is timestamptz,
When i do the query node js result is: Mon Dec 16 2019 03:19:26 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
In node i use `(Date(Date.now())`

I need to know if the records is valid, every record is valid by 30 minutes

My test is:

```js
diffTime = Math.floor(Date.now() - dbField.created_at) / 1000;
var validTime = 1800;
if(validTime < diffTime) {
   console.log('Record is valid');
}
else  {
    console.log('Records is invalid');
}
```

Comment: If you care about database time (and not server time), just use [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to pass on Date-Timestamp from Javascript instead of using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP of DB. This will help you control exact date-time you are storing in database and you can build your logic accordingly and reduce complexity on code level.